# HTTP response code -1 on android phone - using appinventor

Tags: android, http, app-inventor

I am building a simple search app through MIT AppInventor. I have had no problems in querying my spreadsheet shared as public on the cloud.

Suddenly, for no reason, my GET request to the HTTP fails with a response code of -1. I have looked everywhere but can't find an explanation for this -1 code.

Let me repeat that the same block of codes was working perfectly fine until this happened. Now I can't figure out what is going wrong. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem when I found out that my target spreadsheet link, which used to start with http:// was changed to https://. I found that my browser redirected me to https:// when I tried to run my query directly on the web. So changing that in my code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issue recently. It used to work and I found out that my get request was being redirected to a login page being the session had expired.

I suggest you open the get request using the webviewer component (or activitystarter) to give you a better understanding of where the error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you, but what I did was to run the query directly on my browser. Found out it was redirecting me to https: instead of http: